# Image quality control using racket plot/no-gui

Tags: plot, racket

I am using the rakcet language's plot/no-gui library to render functions and I would like to increase the dpi of the images created by the plot-file call. (also any style comments are appreciated)

An example function I am plotting:

```
#lang racket
(require math)
(require plot/no-gui)

(plot-file (list (axes)
            (inverse-interval (λ (x) 1)
                              (λ (x) -1)
                              -3.00000 3.000000)
            (function (lambda (x) (* (expt 3 x) (sin (* 20 x)))) -1 1))
      "images/plot_000000.jpg"
      #:y-min -4
      #:y-max 4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of a plot is controlled by the parameters `plot-width` and `plot-height`.
The image itself doesn't have an dpi - the dpi describes your screen.

Try this:

```
#lang racket
(require math)
(require plot/no-gui)

(define scale 4)
(plot-width  (* scale (plot-width))
(plot-height (* scale (plot-height))

(plot-file (list (axes)
            (inverse-interval (λ (x) 1)
                              (λ (x) -1)
                              -3.00000 3.000000)
            (function (lambda (x) (* (expt 3 x) (sin (* 20 x)))) -1 1))
      "images/plot_000000.jpg"
      #:y-min -4
      #:y-max 4)
```